# Error : The dependency target "gmock" of target "yarpl-tests" does not exist while building yarpl - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, gmock, rsocket

I am trying to build YARPL library that I got using [rsocket library in github](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-cpp/tree/master/yarpl). I followed instructions as mentioned in the readme.

```
# inside root ./yarpl
mkdir -p build
cd build
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG
make -j
./yarpl-tests
```

But in the third step `cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG` I am getting the following output.

```
Compiler has atomic std::shared_ptr support
glog include_dir </usr/include> lib </usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglog.so>
including /home/nsnagekar/fbthrift/thrift/lib/cpp2/transport/rsocket/yarpl
yarpl source dir: /home/nsnagekar/fbthrift/thrift/lib/cpp2/transport/rsocket/yarpl
-- Configuring done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:170 (add_dependencies):
The dependency target "gmock" of target "yarpl-tests" does not exist.


-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nsnagekar/fbthrift/thrift/lib/cpp2/transport/rsocket/yarpl/build
```

Now, **I have installed gmock but it still gives me the same error.** How should I got about it?

P.S. I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** .